# How can I stop a PC from getting teleported by BBEG?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

An evil god wants to teleport the party to his realm to get killed. Fortunately, the PCs go to the Imperial Religious Sect just before the BBEG decides to act. I was just wondering what spell the high priest should use to prevent their teleportation, and what drawbacks/limitations it might have.

Comment: We need to know much more about the situation to advise properly. What level is the high priest? What kind of god/BBEG is this? Is this your DM's own setting or a setting more widely known? What kind of spell is the god/BBEG using to teleport the party? How many are in the party? What are their level(s) and classes? What kind of realm does the god/BBEG inhabit? Etc., etc., yadda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the BBEG is a god - nothing can prevent it doing what it wants, except possibly another god. This is one of the well known advantages of godhood. The sequence of events goes: upset a god -> die.

For anything else *Antimagic Field*, 8th level Abjuration p. 213 PHB.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify, it isn't really a god, just a wannabe god, so it hasn't yet reached full deity status.

Comment: @ARADPLAUG That's the sort of detail that really needs to be in your question.

Comment: @Miniman I know, didn't seem important at the time. I don't know why but it just didn't seem relevant. Sorry.